# Variable in a for of a link

Tags: php

So here I have a table CRUD, it works quite well, only I would like to display a variable of my table in the form of a link redirecting to a file whose name contains the value of the variable :)

I explain in my Numero column, I leave the possibility of entering the value I want, and in fact I would like that according to the value of Numero, when I clicked on (Numero will change according to the different lines) this Redirects to a file: myfile2.html depending on if for example I click on value 2 (first row in my table).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8ZOK.png)

What makes it quite simply allows me to redirect to another table of my own db to the number on which I will click.

I am putting you the code or the modification must be made:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['Severity'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['Origin'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['Numero'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['Remarks'] . "</td>";
```

It's obviously at the level of the line

This is hoping to have been clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: `echo "<

while($row` that should error out as a parse error as an `unexpected while`.

Comment: You're also repeating the same loop. Your post is unclear.

Comment: Who knows @RiggsFolly unsure how to vote to close this, TBH.

Comment: Just REMOVE this `echo "<

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){` and see what happens

Comment: I went for a typo @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly TBH, more like [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them) if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `echo` in your code. Just remove it and it will work.

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Severity'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Origin'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Numero'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Remarks'] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: You might like to add a closing `echo '</tr>';` to save the OP coming back with _it does not work right_

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right. I just changed it. Thanks :)

Comment: I edited the first post, i misscliked on the code but this was not my problem

Comment: Then everythin is ok there @PaulAlex you just need to explain what do you really want to archive